# How can I make a 40x40 grid using divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am basically trying to create using javascript a 40x40 red grid of divs in my html document.

Here's my loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j< 40; j++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.style.width = "25px";
            div.style.height = "25px";
            div.style.background = "red";
        }
        var jump = document.createElement("br");
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(jump);
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
    }
```

The problem is I can't seem to get it to form a square of all the divs I created. The container is 1000 x 1000 px.
Thank you

Comment: did you try adding a width and height with css?

Comment: yes the container is 1000 x 1000 px @ochi

Comment: you'll need to set the CSS float property for all your divs... don't really need js at all

Comment: you're adding a break right after each of the divs and you need to set their display property to inline-block

Comment: @mb21 I can do it in css, but I wanna know how to do it in javascript

Comment: Also make sure you inline them... see answer below

Comment: @Predator44 `div`s by default are block elements (i.e. `display: block`). You need to modify the default to `inline-block` or similar... you can do it in CSS or you can set the property via JS (as in `div.style.display = "inline-block";`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want is the following:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 40; j++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.width = "25px";
        div.style.height = "25px";
        div.style.background = "red";
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
    }
    var jump = document.createElement("br");
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(jump);
}
```

```css
#container {
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
}
#container div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Your inner divs can be inline-block elements so that they flow next to each other (since divs by default are block level). You also need to insert a line break after each inner (j) loop. So the process would be: generate 40 inline divs, insert a line break, generate 40 inline divs, insert a line break,...(repeat 38 more times).

Comment: what happens if I absolute-position the divs?

Comment: Then you'd need to explicitly set the coordinates of each one. Each row would have 40 divs stacked on top of one another. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/exme0ved/

Comment: Is there a way to fix this other than specifying each and every coordinate?

Comment: Do you need to make the inner divs positioned absolutely?

Comment: I need to do it in both ways, so yes.

Comment: Does this work for you http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vd4dcL1y/? It absolutely positions the inner divs using the two loops to set the top and left properties.

Comment: yes! this works perfectly thank you :) nice colors also ;)

Comment: one question, how can can i add the  display, vertical-align via javascript to the css?

Comment: Thank you for your extensive help. Highly appreciated

Comment: Ah... you can make the outer loop run 1600 times, ditch the inner loop and br tag by (i) floating the divs left (ii) add the css `#container > :nth-child(40n+1) {clear: left;}`

Comment: Cowardly, anonymous downvoter care to grow a pair and chime in explaining the problem?

Comment: This could also be done using `div.style.left` and `div.style.position`, by that one can control the spacing of the `div`s.

Answer (score 5):

All you need is to put the last 3 lines inside the inner loop (not inside the outer loop):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j< 40; j++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.width = "25px";
        div.style.height = "25px";
        div.style.background = "red";

        var jump = document.createElement("br");
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(jump);
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to set the 'display' to 'inline-block':

```
div.style.display = "inline-block";
```

Or, you have to use the 'float' attribute:

```
div.style.float = "left";
```

**EDIT:**

Use row-div to group each 40 cells in a row:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("div");
    for(var j = 0; j< 40; j++) {
        var cell = document.createElement("div");
        cell.style.width = "25px";
        cell.style.height = "25px";
        cell.style.background = "red";
        cell.style.display = "inline-block"

        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(row);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the break be in the outer loop instead of after each div?

Comment: this will create a new line for each div added... did you try it?

Comment: I did not realize the idea behind the "br", if you want to make an 40x40 grid just try the code above and remove the break. I hope it will work :)

Comment: if you want to put each 40 div in a line, just add the to a container div, let's name it as "row", then add the 'row' to the 'container'. In this case, you will have 40 group (row-divs), each one have 40 cells (square divs).

Comment: I just edited my answer, and i think this is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to append the created div on each loop iteration.

Second, you need to set the divs as `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j< 40; j++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.style.width = "25px";
            div.style.height = "25px";
            div.style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
        }
    }
```

```css
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}

#container > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a bit of CSS and `inline-block`

`Div`s are typically block elements, you need to make them inline-blocks to help you with your grid.

If you want to remove the line gaps, play with margins (i.e. `margin: 0;` to reduce or `margin: 0 1px;` to add to the sides of each square)

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  var jump = document.createElement("br");

  for (var j = 0; j < 40; j++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "25px";
    div.style.height = "25px";
    div.style.background = "red";
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
  }

  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(jump);
}
```

```css
#container div {
  /* you need this */
  display: inline-block;

}

#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, this actually creates 40 divs in 40 parent divs (like rows):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    var div1 = document.createElement('div')
    for(var j = 0; j< 40; j++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.width = "25px";
        div.style.height = "25px";
        div.style.background = "red";
        div.style.display = 'inline-block';
        div.style.margin = '1px'
        div1.appendChild(div)
    }
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div1);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1jVBeYIMaGfzzgqt7yUj?p=info

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mix of css, html and javascript.

IMHO, the best way is to take advantage of CSS classes and instead of creating each element individually in javascript, you can use `cloneNode()` to clone the first "box".

Here's an example ([**fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/xtqLtpqj/)) and snippet below

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent'),
  box = parent.children[0];

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  var nBox = box.cloneNode(true);
  parent.appendChild(nBox);
}
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="grid">
  <div class="box">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here this will do it for you:

```
<body onload="makeGrid()" id="container">
<body>
<script>
  function makeGrid(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {         
        for(var j = 0; j< 40; j++) {

            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.style.width = "25px";
            div.style.height = "25px";
            div.style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
        }

        //document.getElementById("container").appendChild(jump);
        //document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
    }
    }
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{width: 1000px; height: 1000px;}
div{float: left;}
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/bun4g2d0/9/